# Asterisk change callerid after consultation call

Tags: asterisk

we use an Asterisk as telephone system and have the following issue:

We have multiple phones and want to redirect a call after a consultation.

We get a call from external number and Phone A answers the call. Than he makes a consultation call to Phone B. Phone B answers and talks with Phone A. In this moment the CallerID From Phone A is visible on the Display of Phone B. When Phone A hangs up the call with Phone B. The caller is connected now with Phone B. But on the Display of Phone B is not the CallerID from the external call, but the ID of Phone A.

How I can change the CallerID on the Display of Phone B after Phone A hung up?

**Update:**
A colleague find a solution, we add

```
sendrpid = pai
```

to the sip.conf in the general area. This solved this Problem.

Comment: If you've figured out a solution, please answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague find a solution, we add

```
sendrpid = pai
```

to the sip.conf in the general area. This solved this Problem.